# something errors were thrown out when I was testing the scikit-learn with nosetests

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nosetests

I cannot find how to solve the problem like below. The mac is OS 10.10.3 and python is 2.7.6(the original one in mac). All the way to get the scikit-learn is so smooth except testing. I cannot understand the error at all...

failure is listed below:

======================================================================

### FAIL: sklearn.feature_extraction.tests.test_image.test_connect_regions

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_image.py", line 63, in test_connect_regions
    assert_equal(ndimage.label(mask)[1], connected_components(graph)[0])
AssertionError: 777 != 767

======================================================================

### FAIL: sklearn.feature_extraction.tests.test_image.test_connect_regions_with_grid

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_image.py", line 70, in test_connect_regions_with_grid
    assert_equal(ndimage.label(mask)[1], connected_components(graph)[0])
AssertionError: 777 != 767

---

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in scipy. Upgrade scipy and it'll go away.